# Does this curve represent non-linearity in my residuals vs fitted plot? (simple linear regression)

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression

[image: Residuals vs Fitted]

Hi,

I am running a simple linear regression model in R at the moment and wanted to check my assumptions. As seen by the plot, my red line does not appear to be flat and instead curved in places.

I am having a little difficulty interpreting this - does this imply non-linearity? And if so, what does this say about my data?

Thank you.

Comment: Your image isn't attached

Comment: @Alistair How about now? For me the image is attached.

Comment: I'd say it's inconclusive. I don't see a strong indication that you have a non-linear relationship.

Comment: Apologies, it's on my end

Answer (score 0):

The observation marked 19 on your graph (bottom right corner) seems to have significant influence and is pulling down your line more than other points are pulling it up. The relationship looks linear all in all, getting rid of that outlier by either nullifying it by increasing sample size (Law of large numbers) or removing the outlier(s) should fix your problem without compromising the story your data is trying to tell you and give you the nice graph you're looking for.